# Class instance returns blank Object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out why. I created 2 classes which implement the same interface and set different value to the interface property. When I run the code, One of the classes returns blank object and the other one works as expected.

LinkBinding.ts

```
export enum LinkTypes {
    Custom = 'Custom',
    Page = 'Page'
}

export interface LinkBinding {
    type: LinkTypes
}
```

LinkPage.ts

```
import {LinkBinding, LinkTypes} from "./LinkBinding";

export class LinkPage implements LinkBinding {
    type: LinkTypes = LinkTypes.Page;
    isAbsolute: boolean = false;
}
```

LinkCustom.ts

```
import {LinkBinding, LinkTypes} from "./LinkBinding";

export class LinkCustom implements LinkBinding {
    type: LinkTypes = LinkTypes.Custom;
}
```

LinkCustom.ts to JS

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var LinkBinding_1 = require("./LinkBinding");
var LinkCustom = /** @class */ (function () {
    function LinkCustom() {
        this.type = LinkBinding_1.LinkTypes.Custom;
    }
    return LinkCustom;
}());
exports.LinkCustom = LinkCustom;
```

LinkPage.ts to JS

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var LinkPage = /** @class */ (function () {
    function LinkPage() {
    }
    return LinkPage;
}());
exports.LinkPage = LinkPage;
```

As you can see `LinkCustom.js` has the `type` property but `LinkPage.js` does not.

What is the problem?

Comment: Unable to [repro](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwDIEtEGsAqAnmMAM5wDeAUHLXAMLKkwToC8cA5I865wDQ06ABQCGAc2BwOnMZM5UAvlSqhIsODhjAoAM1EBjKdjwAhHABMc4ykNoxiwAFyYcBR6SUq10eAYA2oqTkJrhyUlioYP7AqEgwIW7miFaINtR0cA4kLqFEJOQceR4AdOEA3HaapACCAEakEP7I2i51EE3AoojScPr+pMCVyqrgvnABQYl4PCzokdGx8dO4yanpVdnOrnj5ZL3FBSWzrMNAA) at the moment. What does your tsconfig look like? Circular reference perhaps?

Comment: I think there must be some problem with your imports, or perhaps your `LinkPage.js` is from an earlier compilation? It [works in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwDIEtEGsAqAnmMAM5wDeAUHLXAMLKkwToC8cA5I865wDQ06ABQCGAc2BwOnMZM5UAvlSqhIsODhjAoAM1EBjKdjwAhHABMc4ykNoxiwAFyYcBR6SUq10eAYA2oqTkJrhyUlioYP7AqEgwIW7miFaINtR0cA4kLqFEJOQceR4AdOEA3HaapACCAEakEP7I2i51EE3AoojScPr+pMCVyqrgvnABQYl4PCzokdGx8dO4yanpVdnOrnj5ZL3FBSWzrMNAA).

Comment: It also works for me locally with this `.tsconfig`: `{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES2015"
    },
    "include": [
        "*.ts"
    ]
}` The resulting `LinkPage.js` has `type`: https://pastebin.com/Mt5K4kTK

Comment: After viewing your playground's code working. I took a look at my project's directory. For every typescript file there was a JavaScript file I have compiled long time before and I didn't delete them. Typescript loaded those JavaScript files instead of the typescript files. After deleting the JavaScript files Typescript recompiled the `.ts` files. The `LinkPage.ts` and the other files are used as library in another Typescript project. I do not need to add there path to tsconfig.json` of the other project.

Answer (score 0):

After viewing the playground's code in the comments above working. I took a look at my project's directory. For every typescript file there was a JavaScript file I have compiled long time before and I didn't delete them. Typescript or webpack loaded those JavaScript files instead of the typescript files. After deleting the JavaScript files Typescript recompiled the `.ts` files. The `LinkPage.ts` and the other files are used as library in another Typescript project. I do not need to add there path to `tsconfig.json` of the other project.

Here is my directory structure:

- src

  - VueJs project (Typescript)
  - My library project (Typescript)

The `My library project` referenced in the `VueJs project`. So, I don't include the `My library project` into `My library project/tsconfig.json`. Deleting the js files in `My library project` made it work.